# Create two models with one create

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

While creating a `League` I'm trying to also create a join association called `UsersLeagues`. Here is my current attempt:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
      |> cast(params, [:name])
      |> validate_required([:name])
      |> put_assoc(:users_leagues,UsersLeagues.changeset(%UsersLeagues{}, user_id: 1, league_id: 1, commissioner: true))
end
```

When I try to create with that changeset I get this error. `expected params to be a :map, got: [user_id: 1, league_id: 1, commissioner: true]`

I'm not sure what it's trying to tell me?

Again, I'm trying to create one model and in that process create a join table.

Comment: To fix this error, try `%{user_id: 1, ...}` instead of `user_id: 1, ...`. Not sure if the rest is correct.

Comment: It still has an error:
#Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{name: "new"},
 errors: [users_leagues: {"is invalid", [type: {:array, :map}]}],
 data: #Statcasters.League<>, valid?: false>

Comment: I can't test right now but does wrapping the changeset in a list work? `put_assoc(:users_leagues, [UsersLeagues.changeset(...)])`?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my suggestion? or have you solved it some other way?

Comment: @Dogbert I haven't had time to continue. But, I'm working on this tonight. I'll get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
struct
  |> cast(params, [:name])
  |> validate_required([:name])
  |> put_assoc(:users_leagues,UsersLeagues.changeset(%UsersLeagues{user_id: 1, league_id: 1, commissioner: true}))
end
```

try this

Changeset is used to validate data before insert it into the data base.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I look at my failing changeset it gives me this error: 

#Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{name: "make it"},
 errors: [users_leagues: {"is invalid", [type: {:array, :map}]}],
 data: #Statcasters.League<>, valid?: false>

Comment: That error probably means your UsersLeagues.changeset is invalid. Ecto can create the join record without much intervention and somehow that user_id: 1, league_id: 1 doesn't seem right. Hard to tell more without seeing the schemas and migrations. In this free e-book it has a nice example of many_to_many in chapters 8 and 9. http://pages.plataformatec.com.br/ebook-whats-new-in-ecto-2-0

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `UserLeagues` is supposed to be a map, but it's a keyword list. Change the second-to-last line to this:

```
  |> put_assoc(:users_leagues,UsersLeagues.changeset(%UsersLeagues{}, %{user_id: 1, league_id: 1, commissioner: true}))
```